# Redirecting null make file unreadable

Tags: solaris, logfile, dev-null

I am using solaris OS. the problem is when is redirect `/dev/null` to a "growing big log file", it becomes unreadable. Also it helps to decrease the file size to zero, but I can not open it with `less` command `du` to error that says it is "binary file, do you want to open it?"

Do you know how to work around this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with *redirect* `/dev/null`? If you feed `/dev/null` it will - afaik - become an empty (binary) file.

Comment: This question is unclear and doesn't seem to be about programming.

Comment: I have a bash script that finds big log files and clears them regularly. 
As the log file is growing i cant remove the file. so I redirect null using "> logfile" to clear content of the big file and have some space.

Comment: *I am using solaris OS. the problem is when is redirect /dev/null to a "growing big log file", it becomes unreadable*  And this is why using redirected `stdout`/`stderr` for logging is an indication that the developer **doesn't know what he's doing**. As you are finding out, it doesn't work very well for large log files and long-lived processes.